# how i can get menu item of tray icon which is added by some other class

Tags: java, automation, tray

// TrayUtilitiesDemo is a call which is returning me tray icon create by current java process.

```
MyMenu.setLabel("MyMenu");
TrayUtilitiesDemo.addPopupMenu(MyMenu);
TrayIcon trayIcon = TrayUtilitiesDemo.getTrayIcon();
System.out.println("TrayIcons are: "+trayIcon);
```

when i am doing

```
trayIcon.getPopupMenu().countItems();
```

it is retrun only 1 menuitem. which is added by me that is MyMenu.
there are other 4 menuitems are there added by some other class which is creating this tray icon.

and not able to get the ActionListener also. 
basically i want to right click on tray icon click and click on menuitem in PopupMenu added by other class(or by other process) for automation.
using windows 7 machine.

please help.

Comment: can you share TrayUtilitiesDemo methods source

Comment: sorry i am from test department, i am not having access of that source code that name too i have changed. but some methods are there those i can use are like, addpopupmenu(),InitTraicon/showtrayicon/addlisteners. so was looking some direct way in java.

Comment: seems TrayUtilitiesDemo maintains a singleton TrayIcon and provides utilities to work with it. Since the sequence of adding menuItems is not known, I can only assume that by the time you print count the other menuItems are not added in TrayIcon.